# Localize iphone application with a application defined language

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization

Heey,

I can localize my iPhone app with the systems local by localizing the nib files and adding a Localizable.strings file to my project.

Is there a way to set the language to a application specific language and then load the correct stings/files?

(The idea comes from an Canadian, he wants his device in english, but some apps in french)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following and it works

```
//Set the language
NSArray *languages=[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"es"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Cheers